# Exclude field dynamically from $match, $and in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to implement Search with filters. Search includes 'is_published' & 'title'. For this search result I want to apply filters like 'size', 'height', 'format' using $match & $and. I may include either of these filters or none.

```
{"$match": {"is_published": {"$ne": 2}}},
{"$match": {"$or": [
                    {"title": "Flower"},
                ]}},
{"$match": {"$and": [
                    {"size": <dynamic_value_from_front_end>},
                    {"height": <dynamic_value_from_front_end>},
                    {"format": <dynamic_value_from_front_end>}

                ]}}
```

Based on the '**dynamic_value_from_front_end**', I want to exclude some fields from filter (from $and) query(not from the output but from the 'query') when the 'dynamic_value_from_front_end' is **empty**.

If I keep '{"size": null}', it searches for where 'size' is 'null' but I totally want to omit {"size": null}' from query.
How can I achieve this?

Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: How do you define "In some cases"?

Comment: In applying filter for size, height, format. If the size filter is applied remaining two fields should be excluded.

Comment: @Cherry : I believe this question can be better be explained with sample docs & required o/p for all scenarios !!

Comment: Edited to add the requirement

Comment: @Cherry Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. MongoDB questions better have example documents and I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the array you want to pass in the $and in your third $match in the pipeline and just pass that array to $and.

So it's not clear exactly what the "conditions" are where you want to pass or omit a value, so I'm going to assume the following:

Say you are getting the data from the front end as an object `query` with three possible properties, `size` `height` and `format` which may contain some value or `null`, or may not exist at all. If you get `size`, you want the other two omitted, else you want either `height` or `format` or both, depending on their availablilty.

So I've mocked some values for the input parameters and written what a possible solution could look like (assuming Node.js on the backend since you did not specify):

```js
const input1 = {
 size: 30,
 format: "f-1",
 length: 50
}

const input2 = {
 format: "f-2"
}


const getFilterConditionsFromInput = (input) => {
 const filterConditions = [];

 if(typeof(input.size)==="number"){
  filterConditions.push({
   size: input.size
  });
 } else {
  if(typeof(input.format)==="string"){
   filterConditions.push({
    format: input.format
   })
  }
  if(typeof(input.length)==="number"){
   filterConditions.push({
    length: input.length
   })
  }
 }
 return filterConditions;
}

console.log(getFilterConditionsFromInput(input1));
console.log(getFilterConditionsFromInput(input2));
```

Note that the type checks were necessary, since for numbers, `0` is considered "falsey" in javascript, so if the size or length is supplied as 0, they would get omitted, which may not be desired (don't know for sure because you did not specify).

Now you can just plug the result of this function into your pipeline:

```
{
    "$match": {
        "$and": getFilterConditionsFromInput(inputObject)
    }
}
```

Also, a sidenote: the object you supply in $match, from what I know, functions almost exactly like in "find" so the conditions are ANDed by default, so I'm not sure why you're using $and in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar, using if-else with variables instead of array push. Anyway I changed it to array push(Python). If the 'inputObject' is empty i.e. no size, height, filter fields, then $match and $and throws error. How it can be handled ?

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :)